# spring-boot with the gradle java java-plugin

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, jar

I use gradle with the new java-library plugin.
With this plugin we can use new configurations for dependencies instead of 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' etc.
[see java-library plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html)

But with the spring-boot plugin, when I launch the task

> gradle build

The produced jar does not contain the dependencies of the project.
It is because I use the 'implementation' configuration.
If I use 'compile' configuration as I did before, it works.

Is there a solution, to use these new configurations ?
Or do you plan to implement this new feature in the next versions of spring-boot.

Thank you :)